# How to make shape-shifting robotic creatures?

Tags: metals, cybernetics, cyborg, android

**BORN4 / Con-Science Saga**

Is this story scientifically possible and/or plausible by our real-world standards?

What should I change about it, if the science behind it is not really understandable?

In the not-so-far future of this nation, a technologically advanced terrorist organization, simply named "Con-Science", starts their invasion of our homeland. But was it for the better or worse, we ask? Soon they start constructing a new type of civilization all together, a society where everything seems perfect. The military leaders of Con-Science do not want to destroy cities or landmarks, instead they build huge domed villages out in the middle of nowhere with large gazing fields where no one else lived beforehand.

Secretly to the public eye, the bio-engineers of Con-Science plan to create four cyborg/android super-enhanced safety sentinels to enforce their power as the one-world government.

Project BORN4 | Prime Directive = "Kill the Bad - Save the Good"

Their old and dying president, Tiberius Becker, had been injected with a strange, mysterious form of compound energy, namely materialized neutrinos. Neutrinos are subatomic particles that interact only with weak subatomic force and gravity, rarely reacting with normal matter. His father had experimented on his own son, Tiberius, to find a way to materialize neutrinos and see what kind of effects they had on living organisms. From an early age in Tiberius's life, these injections of energy resulted in many super-powers, like superior strength, speed and increased visual and auditive perception. The materialized neutrinos had eventually driven themselves into his DNA and from then on soaked his every fiber with the super-powered mutagen that Con-Science needed.

In order to create the ultimate life-form, Con-Science and Tiberius were willing to sacrifice their president for the greater good. They hooked him up to a blood-drawing machine which would slowly and gently pump the various DNA streams from Tiberius resulting in killing him.

The four tubes of DNA (four colors of blood) are hooked up to four very tall cloning-vats full of genetically-stable liquid and the designer babies that would soon become the "Born4" safety sentinels.

The reason why Tiberius was not fully unstoppable and unbreakable was because his mortal body was made out of flesh just like any other animal. These four intelligently designed creatures were not human, they were made to look like humans, but they were most definitely not "organic" in any shape or form. Their bodies are made out of DNX, a genetic structure closely related to human DNA, but an artificial substance made from compounding that same DNA with a cybernetic robot structure of nano-threading stitched together. In genetic terms, a designer baby is a baby developed from an embryo created by in-vitro fertilization and selected because it possessed or lacked particular genes. The genetic make-up of Con-Science babies often had to be modified by genetic engineering, the perfect system setup for the Born4 Project.

People feared that this robot would become a special breed of superhuman, something so strong that you could not stop it, if your life depended on it.

Born4 "Quart" Members (modelled after the four humors, these substances outline the Born4’s distinct personality types which will be their strong suits):

- Sanguine Spade (blood) - red/pink, male European, the Popular Entertainer, Personality=enthusiastic, active and social
- Choleric Club (yellow bile) - yellow/orange, male Native American, the Powerful Leader, Personality=short-tempered, fast and irritable
- Melancholy Diamond (black bile) - black/violet, female Asian, the Sensitive Perfectionist, Personality=analytical, wise and quiet
- Phlegmatic Heart (phlegm) - white/aqua, female African, the Calm Peacekeeper, Personality=relaxed and peaceful

Since their bodies are practically made out of liquid metal, the Born4 characters can shape-shift in any shape imaginable to terrify their victims. They see into the "souls" of human people by sensing their conscious aura radiating around them. If it is evil, they kill and eat the flesh of that person for their batteries' fuel source. While at the same time, they save all the innocents they can find in perilous danger, thus the duality of Con-Science.

Do this process of making shape-shifting cyborgs/androids/robots make actual sense?

Comment: Nothing containing the phrase "conscious aura radiating around them" will ever make sense. But it doesn't matter. LotR also doesn't make sense (don't tell me that it does, please, unless your best friend is an Orc).  I think if you just want pure evaluation of how good your concepts/your story is, there are better places on the web.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, WaterFireRTH, this is a rich mix. A powerful leader who is short-tempered, fast and irritable wouldn't make a good leader. Either Phlegmatic or Melancholy sound like better choices.

Comment: In a hand-waving sense, "nanotechnology" is your best bet for "shape shifting - somewhat realistic technology".

Comment: You might find my [Lessons](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/lessons-in-writing-questions) post interesting, to help you get a question out of your story-info-dump.

Comment: Teenage Mutant Ninja... Transformers?

Comment: Make actual sense?  No. *materialized neutrinos* is not at all sense. This reads like a comic book… I don’t think you want to make it hard sci-fi.

Comment: I second nanobots.

Answer (score 3):

"These four intelligently designed creatures were not human, they were made to look like humans, but they were most definitely not "organic" in any shape or form. Their bodies are made out of DNX, a genetic structure closely related to human DNA, but an artificial substance made from compounding that same DNA with a cybernetic robot structure of nano-threading stitched together. In genetic terms, a designer baby is a baby developed from an embryo created by in-vitro fertilization and selected because it possessed or lacked particular genes. The genetic make-up of Con-Science babies often had to be modified by genetic engineering, the perfect system setup for the Born4 Project."

Frankly this isn't science as I known it. genetic engineering without genes is a contradiction in terms. With or without nano-threading.

"Since their bodies are practically made out of liquid metal, the Born4 characters can shape-shift in any shape imaginable to terrify their victims. They see into the "souls" of human people by sensing their conscious aura radiating around them. If it is evil, they kill and eat the flesh of that person for their batteries' fuel source."

I don't understand how their bodies can be liquid metal. Eating flesh to power their batteries is moderately plausible. if the batteries were metabolic, organic batteries. the main drawback is they wouldn't be very powerful batteries.

"Do this process of making shape-shifting cyborgs/androids/robots make actual sense?" No it doesn't.

I recommend simply saying the shape-shifting androids/robots, but definitely not cyborgs, have liquid metal bodies and leave it at that. Ditto with the source of Tiberius' super-powers. Materialized neutrinos don't make any sense at all. Anyone who even know a miniscule amount about neutrinos will know this is unscientific.

You need to follow the First Law of Rubber Science: Never try to explain more than you know. It would take heavy-duty knowledge of science and technology to devise a remotely plausible explanation for super-powers and shape-shifting robots. Steer clear of pseudoscientific technobabble for your own sake.

Therefore, a secret something gives Tiberius super-powers and the shape-shifting androids/robots have liquid metal bodies. That's it. All the explanation you need. Now get on with the story.

ADDENDUM:

If you have liquid metal robots, then if that technology can be integrated into living creatures, for example, human beings this will enable the creation of cyborgs. Tiberius could be a liquid metal technology cyborg. This could explain his super-powers. He is a combination of technology and biology. The liquid metal technology could provide a dying old man with life support, it could effectively rejuvenate him, and give him the equivalent of super-powers.

This also has the advantage that you only need to introduce one major innovation -- the liquid metal robotic technology -- and this gives you shape-shifting androids/robots and a super-powered cyborg.

Comment: You're right about their batteries not being very powerful batteries. They are organic, but the Born4 must eat anything that has some sort of nutrients to gain extra energy, besides meat. But like a little something more from how these creatures could grow up to become anything science-related, maybe something else could replace the neutrinos, I'm not really attached to that part of the story. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: "[Biomatter Conversion](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Biomatter_Conversion)" can account for how your machines consume living things for fuel. They basically break down the living tissue, liquify it, and burn it. It's like how the dinosaurs eventually became crude oil, but massively accelerated so that it takes minutes instead of millenia.

Comment: @WaterFire.RTH Instead of batteries they could have fuel cells which will generate more power. A few decades ago they developed fuel cells that ran on hydrazine. Hydrazine is good for power, environmentally clean in exhaust products (nitrogen & water vapor), but it is poisonous, corrosive, and explosive.

Comment: @WaterFire.RTH I have edited my answer and added extra ideas for a possible explanation for Tiberius' super-powers. Please use the ideas in my answer, if you find them useful, as a starting point for a world. Have fun with it!